# Android In App Billing SecurityException "Binder invocation to an incorrect interface"

Tags: android, in-app-billing, aidl, securityexception

I am trying to get the google In App Billing services to work.

I've got so far that the service is bound and connected, but once I try to fetch some data from the service it crashes with the log:

`04-02 10:36:32.795  10569-10651/my.app.package E/IAP﹕ java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
            at billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.getSkuDetails(IInAppBillingService.java:251)
            at my.app.package.libs.clientbackend.iap.IAPHelper$FetchItemsCallable.call(IAPHelper.java:102)
            at my.app.package.libs.clientbackend.iap.IAPHelper$FetchItemsCallable.call(IAPHelper.java:89)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)`

This is my code so far:

The activity that shows the Purchases:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
bindService(serviceIntent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

The IAB calls once the service has connected:

```
Bundle itemBundle = new Bundle();
itemBundle.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(itemIds)));
Bundle detailsBundle = service
        .getSkuDetails(3, context.getPackageName(), "inapp", itemBundle);
```

It fails on the last line `...getSkuDetails(...` with the error posted above.

---

I did some research on this matter and found our that it might be caused by wrong package names. I've included the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` like it's described on google's documentation but I am still getting a wrong package on import:

The file is at: `src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl`

But when I am importing the generated class Android Studio uses this import path:

```
import billing.IInAppBillingService;
```

According to the documentation this should actually be:

```
import com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;
```

Is there still something wrong with my project setup or does anyone know the cause of this error?

Much thanks in advance,
McFarlane

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem and I figured out that aidl file must be in the `com.android.vending.billing` package in src folder but you put that in `src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing` which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I follow this steps from https://developer.android.com

Copy the IInAppBillingService.aidl file to your project.

> If you are using Android Studio, complete these steps to copy the
>   file:
>           Navigate to src/main in the Project tool window.
>           Select File > New > Directory, enter aidl in the New Directory window, and select OK.
>           Select File > New > Package, enter com.android.vending.billing in the New Package window, and select OK.
>           Using your operating system file explorer, navigate to <sdk>/extras/google/play_billing/, copy the
>   IInAppBillingService.aidl file, and paste it into the
>   com.android.vending.billing package in your project.

I create aidl folder and then in this folder create package com.android.vending.billing, and my import is still import billing.IInAppBillingService; I try to add package in src but IInAppBillingService.java is not generated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem due to using In App Billing v2 and thinking it was the v3 version. Oops :)